# Django SlugField not unique

Tags: django

I'm stuck from a couple hours and I can't solve this problem.

The following code works well, but if I write a "Title" that already exist I get:

```
UNIQUE constraint failed: appname_shopaccount.url_shop
```

Model

```
class ShopAccount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    url_shop = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url_shop = slugify(self.title)
        super(ShopAccount, self).save(*args, **kwargs)    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Forms

```
class SignUpShopForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = ShopAccount
        fields=['title', 'company_name']        
        exclude= ('user',)

        error_messages = {
            'title': {
                'required': "Enter a Shop name",
            },                                    
            'company_name': {
                'required': "Enter a Company name",
            }
        }
```

View

```
def signup_shop(request):    
    if request.POST:
        form = SignUpShopForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            account = form.save(commit=False)
            account.user = request.user
            account.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/account/updated/')
        else:
           form = SignUpShopForm(data=request.POST)
           return render_to_response('register_shop.html', { 'form':form }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:        
        return render_to_response('register_shop.html', context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Remove `unique=True` from the `url_shop` field in your model and update your database with `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`.

Be aware though that a slug field that can have non-unique values might have consequences for your app depending on how you are using it (two objects having the same url for example)

Answer (score 1):

You can use unique_slugify to force a unique slug- https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/690/

```
import unique_slugify

class ShopAccount(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.url_shop = unique_slugify(self, self.title, slug_field_name='url_shop')
        super(ShopAccount, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

If the slug being created already exists, unique_slugify will append a '-1' (and on upwards) to the slug until a unique slug is found. Keep `unique=True` in your url_shop model kwargs :]

The reason you have an issue with your existing code is that `slugify` only converts the title field to a slug, not checking for existing slug values. With the method above, `unique_slugify` will check existing values and generate a slug that does not exist in the db yet.

Comment: This also may work for you, though I have never tried it out - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-autoslug. I can vouch for unique_slugify being a pretty dang simple method.